# Would a Spiked Shield magically enhanced as a shield and a Magic Ki Focus work together?

Tags: dnd-4e, fighter, monk

As the title, I want to know if its technically possible to use a Magic Ki Focus with a Spiked Shield.

I know that if you had a magical weapon and a Ki focus, at the time of attacking, you choose which you want to benefit off of for the weapon (the magic enhancement or the ki-focus enhancement) and that is what you use for the duration of the attack.  However, a Spiked Shield still retains itself being a spiked shield when its enhanced as a shield so it still has the proficiency and the damage, just no enhancement.  So wouldn't the Ki-Focus have an option of temporarily making it a magical weapon at the time of attacking as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ki Focus[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=568)

> If you have both a magic ki focus and a magic weapon, you choose before you use an attack power whether to draw on the magic of the ki focus or that of the weapon. Your choice determines which enhancement bonus, critical hit effects, and magic item properties and powers you can apply to that power.

If the Spiked Shield is enchanted as a weapon, you only get one enchantment bonus, and only one set of properties.

If the Spiked Shield is enchanted as a shield, RAW, you do not benefit from properties that may apply to the attack you are making. Properties that apply to anything else continue to apply.

For example, the defence bonus on a charge from a Tusk Shield would still be applied.

Comment: So basically if I use a Spiked Shield enchanted with Tusk Shield, and have Magic Ki-Focus +2, and I charge an enemy with a Melee Basic Attack with the Shield, I'd get the +2 to defenses until the end of my next turn as well as the +2 enhancement bonus to my attack roll, damage roll, and if I crit, my 2d6 crit dice extra?

Comment: Yes. Using the enhancement bonus, critical dice and properties of the Ki Focus prohibit using the enhancement bonus, critical dice and properties of any weapon you may also be using *for the attack power* - charge is not an attack power, it just lets you use a melee basic attack or bull rush (which are attack powers).

Comment: (and not quite yes, since you put **end** rather than **beginning** of your next turn for the defence bonus)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response.
Thanks for that response, that helped quite a bit since that just seemed massively confusing since I don't think that really came up before.